# setValidators is not working angular reactive form

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form which is based upon angular-material

```
if(deviceType === 'source' && deviceName.value) {
  alert('hhhh')
  this.topoMappForm.get('portA').setValidators(Validators.required)
  this.topoMappForm.get('portA').disable();
}
```

in this alert is called and disable is called, but setValidators is not working because  submit button is showing enabled

```
<button type="button" [disabled]='topoMappForm.invalid' md-button class="btn btn--primary" (click)="addPort();">Add Port</button>
```

Please help

Comment: `this.topoMappForm.updateValueAndValidity()`

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
this.topoMappForm.get('portA').setValidators([Validators.required])
```